# QComboBox drop-down list adding unnecessary scroll bar

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qcombobox

I'm creating a `QComboBox` in an app with just 2 items in it. This should appear without a scroll bar, but it seems to be creating the drop-down list very fractionally too small for the information in it, causing it to create a vertical scroll bar.

It feels as though it's slightly mis-read the text size when calculating the size of the created list.

Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: A simple code to see the problem?

Comment: It's created through a framework that I can't share... I'll see if I can replicate it in more simple form.

Answer (score 1):

One of the ways to adjust width and height of drop down list of QComboBox is to use css:

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/13496-CSS-QCombobox-setting-min-height-for-drop-down-list

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to add long items into my dropdown list. It appears to me that there is no scroll bar.

```
self.symbol = QtGui.QComboBox(GoogleFinance)
self.symbol.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 40, 200, 21))
self.symbol.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("symbol"))
self.symbol.addItem("Helloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo")
self.symbol.addItem("what's upppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppppp")
```

[image]

Comment: I just edited my question a little - it's a vertical scroll bar rather than a horizontal one.